# How to delete rows where two columns are both blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an Excel worksheet with Columns A-G.
And hundreds of rows.

There are sometimes numbers in column F and sometimes in column G.

How can I only delete the rows when columns F and G are both blank?

<kbd>F5</kbd> → “Special” → “Blanks” would work if I was only searching for blanks on one of those columns. But they both have to be blank.

Answer (score 2):

Filter your columns and select the blank values in both columns. This will return all rows where F and G are blank and you can delete them.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a spare column (such as `H`). 
Enter `=(F1&G1)=""` into `H1` and drag/fill down. 
This is `TRUE` if Columns `F` and `G` are both blank,
and `FALSE` otherwise. 
Filter on Column `H` and display only the `TRUE` rows.

Select your entire data range
and do <kbd>F5</kbd> → “Special” and select “Visible cells only”. 
(<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>**;**</kbd> is a shortcut for this.) 
Then delete the selected rows.